# How do I write a function function(n) that takes in an integer, and returns the sum of the first n even numbers using a while loop?

Tags: python

How do I write a function function(n) that takes in an integer, and returns the sum of the first n even numbers using a while loop?
Example: function(3) returns 12 because the first three even numbers are 2, 4, 6.

My code:

```
def function(n):
        result = 0
        while i < 2*n+1:
                if not i%2==1:
                        result += i
        return result
```

However the result I get was "i" was not defined. I appreciate help and thanks!

Comment: So, you need to define the variable `i`.

Comment: `````
def function(n):
        i = 0
        result = 0
        while i < 2*n+1:
                if not i%2==1:
                        result += i
                        i += 1
        return result
``````````

Comment: you need to initiate `i` at the beginning of the function; and also make sure that the condition will be valid, currently this is not the case

Comment: I tried this but also did not work :(

Comment: Are you sure you want to solve this by brute force instead of applying mathematics (sum formula of arithmetic progression)?

Comment: Do you want to increment i somewhere?

Comment: @Elssie Please don't update the code in your question after asking it and receiving answers and comments, that renders them irrelevant and impossible to understand. Just leave it as it originally was, the answers and corrections are to be found in the answers. ;) I rolled back the question to its previous state.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to declare i and increment it with each loop

```
def func(n):
   result = 0
   i = 0
   while i < 2*n+1:
      if i%2 == 0:
         result += i
      i += 1
   return result
```

Comment: Increment by 2 as well (and drop the if)

Comment: Tried to keep it as similar to the original code as possible to make the error more clear if the problem occurs again in the future.

Comment: Ahh I see I have placed i+=1 under the wrong indentation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not trying to make the most efficient code, the purpose of this response is to show where his error was. The most effective way to accomplish this is to leave it as close to the original as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined variable `i` and aren't incrementing the `i` in your for loop and that's why you have an infinite loop.

The code should look like this:

```
def function(n):
    i = 0
    result = 0
    while i < 2 * n + 1:
        if not i % 2:
            result += i
        i += 1
    return result
```

However, the clean ways of doing this are given below:

```
# Time complexity of O(n)
def fun(n):
    result = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        result += 2*i
    return result

# Efficient as having time complexity of O(1)
def fun2(n):
    return n * (n + 1)

print(fun2(3))
print(fun(3))
```

You can use `fun2` as it has time complexity of `O(1)`. See [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-first-n-even-numbers/) to learn more.

Comment: In `fun2` I would prefer the loop to have a step width of 2 instead of multiplying.

Comment: You mean `func`. Yes this can be done too and would be faster as well.

Answer (score 1):

@TreysenZobell [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59443155/5168011) explained the problem. Another  one line solution is to use built-in `sum()`

```
def function(n):
    return sum([i for i in range(2 * n + 1) if i % 2 == 0])
```

Comment: You're welcome! You could also `return sum(i for i in range(2, 2*n+1, 2))`

Answer (score 0):

Less elegant than some of these fancy pants one-liners but wanted to add a `while True` answer:

```
def fn(num):
    vals, counter = 0, 0
    even_nums = []
    while True:
        if vals < num:
            counter += 2
            even_nums.append(counter)
            vals += 1
        else:
            return sum(even_nums)
```